# Exynos4_PPMU Struct Explanation

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, driver, linux-device-driver

I am looking at the exynos4_bus.c file in the Linux kernel (drivers/devfreq) and have encountered this struct:

```
struct exynos4_ppmu {
    void __iomem *hw_base;
    unsigned int ccnt;
    unsigned int event;
    unsigned int count[PPMU_PMNCNT_MAX];
    bool ccnt_overflow;
    bool count_overflow[PPMU_PMNCNT_MAX];
};
```

I was wondering if somebody could explain to me roughly what exactly a PPMU is and what purpose it might serve in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: [Kernel documenation](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/exynos/power_domain.txt) and [commit message](http://lkml.org/lkml/2013/1/9/175)

According to the [source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/drivers/devfreq/exynos4_bus.c), this seems to be a [DVFS (dynamic voltage and frequency scaling)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_and_frequency_scaling) IP for a Samsung ARM processor, relating to the memory/bus frequency.  Statistics are collected in this structure, eg. `exynos4_read_ppmu()`, to determine how the voltage and frequency are performing.  See for example, `exynos4_get_busier_dmc()`.  I don't see off hand if the DVFS is automated by the controller or by software; I can't find a publicly available data sheet.